# Magento 1.9 configurable swatches ordered by position

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, swatches

When I use the new configurable swatches with Magento 1.9.1, the configurable items are not sorted like in the drop-down.

For example sizes, I want sizes sorted like S, M, L, XL. That is also how I sorted them by position in the attribute settings.

Now with the configurable swatches they seem sorted at random, like M, XL, S, L. It's not alphabetical or in position, I can't figure out what is going wrong.

After setting up the use of these swatches I re-indexed and cleared cache.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and applied the 2nd fix given here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270918/magento-1-9-1-not-sorting-configurable-product-attributes-dropdown-by-position:

> [...] copy
>   app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php
>   to local folder
>   app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php
>   and apply this patch:
>
> ```
> Index: app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php
> ===================================================================
> --- app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php
> +++ app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php
> @@ -301,7 +301,28 @@
>                      }
>                  }
>              }
>
> +            /**
> +             * Mage 1.9+ fix for configurable attribute options not sorting to position
> +             * @author Harshit <support@cubixws.co.uk>
> +             */
> +            $sortOrder = 1;
> +            foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
> +                $productAttribute = $item->getProductAttribute();
> +                if (!($productAttribute instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract)) {
> +                    continue;
> +                }
> +                $options = $productAttribute->getFrontend()->getSelectOptions();
> +                foreach ($options as $option) {
> +                    if (!$option['value']) continue;
> +                    if (isset($values[$item->getId() . ':' . $option['value']])) {
> +                        $values[$item->getId() . ':' . $option['value']]['order'] = $sortOrder++;
> +                    }
> +                }
> +            }
> +            usort($values, function($a, $b) {
> +                return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
> +            });
> +            
>              foreach ($values as $data) {
>                  $this->getItemById($data['product_super_attribute_id'])->addPrice($data);
>              }
> ```
>
> If you are hesitant of copying across a core file to local folder then
>   I can create a quick module, `<rewrite>` this Collection.php file and
>   just override the _loadPrices() function and introduce this fix.

You just have to copy the core file to app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php and add the given code - it was line 304 for me.

It worked fine for my size attribute swatches.