# Magento 1.9.1 Configurable Swatches not sorting Size Field Correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product, sorting, swatches

I have enabled configurable swatches for my store, and it looks great. We are displaying shirts, and sizes as our configurable attributes. I would like to sort the size attribute by position, and have set the positions accordingly so that they should sort XS, S, M, L, XL, etc. This worked correctly before the swatches were enabled.

Sizes display in a seemingly random order. I have done some searching and found that there is a reported bug that the options display in the order of the simple product's product ID. I have tried a couple of these fixes without success:

These are the one's I've tried.

Answer 1 on this page:
[Magento 1.9.1 configurable product attribute sorting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45396/magento-1-9-1-configurable-product-attribute-sorting)

The one answer on this page:
[Magento 1.9 configurable swatches ordered by position](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58679/magento-1-9-configurable-swatches-ordered-by-position)

I did clear all of the caches after loading these patches, and I still have the second one in place, but it doesn't appear to have effected the sort order of the size swatches.

I really appreciate any help you can give me on this.

Thanks!
Vi